# Setting up wordpress to use remote cloud based storage

Tags: wordpress, cloud-storage

I have a site with a large number of images, I'd like to host these on a remote cloud storage solution as we're getting close to our storage limit on the current server.

I can get a remote cloud storage service setup, what needs to be done on wordpress configuration to use this as the new folder for uploads?

Thanks

Comment: much will depend on the cloud service you use. the question is very vague

Comment: I'm assuming the configuration on the wordpress site will be the same,  it will reference remote storage, using a url and access details.

Comment: But…but…every cloud storage provider is different. How is WordPress going to "just know" how to do this?

Comment: Wordpress has configuration details, I'm curious to know how and what needs to be changed so it can use this remote storage rather than the local default storage.

Comment: It'll be more hard to make some plugins work( some plugins using upload dir of wordpress to write into files some information ), than just use images from remote server. It maybe will be more easy for you just to serve images in the remote server and in the wordpress add that remote servers images url

Answer (score 0):

**Specifically for AWS S3:**

The company I work for use this: https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-s3/ and it's worked a treat!

This should handle the automatic upload of your old media, plus updating your posts/pages. To be safe, download a local copy of your WP and database, and run all it locally using a test bucket. Or, have a back up on to hand if the upload doesn't work. Can't be too safe!

We've only had one issue with it this past week and it's when you upload a file but change the file extension afterwards, it never off-loaded that particular image to S3 and continue to load the old `/wp-content/<year>/<month>` version.

Comment: Thanks for that, we have several hundreds of thousands of images so the cost the for that solution  won't work for us. 

I came across w3-total-cache, that might fit the bill.